# cmd bat file, allow access to network share

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-permissions

I have the below code which works excellently to compare 2 latest files and output the difference into a separate folder However in the :getLatestFileInFolder I need it to access the SAN network location. Currently it can only access local. Can someone tweak this code for me please. The location I need to access is on the san "\3663vfas01\Biztalk$\Live"

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\AX copy
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /od /a-d /tw') do (set latest=%%a)   

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

call :getLatestFileInFolder "C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\AX copy" latestC
call :getLatestFileInFolder "C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\Reflex copy" latestD


if not defined latestC ( echo NO File in C & exit /b )
if not defined latestD ( echo NO File in D & exit /b )

for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (
    'diff "%latestC%" "%latestD%" ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
) do (
    >> "C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\Error\%latest%" echo(%%b
)

endlocal
exit /b

:getLatestFileInFolder folderToSearch variableToReturn
setlocal
set "folder=%~1" & if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"
set "latest="
pushd "%folder%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d /tw 2^>nul') do (set "latest=%%~fa" & goto :latestFileFound)
:latestFileFound
popd
endlocal & set "%~2=%latest%" & goto :eof
```

Comment: I don't know about your san, but,  should not the path to the resource start with a double backslash?

Comment: Hi the above code works as all the testing is on local. The san has double \\ "\\3663vfas01\Biztalk$\Live"

Comment: And when you run the code with the path to the SAN, what is the problem you get?

Comment: The cmd box opens and closes (no error messages) and no file is generated in the error folder

Comment: Try it with `echo on` and include a `pause` command before the `exit /b` to see where it fails.

Comment: It runs quite a lot of the code and then says "no such file or directory"

Comment: Hi MC ND, the below code worked. Thank you for helping me with this, you've been a lot of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EDITED
```

Change this line:

```
set "fC=C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\AX copy"
```

to this:

```
set "fC=\\3663vfas01\Biztalk$\Live"
```

in this code, which should function as yours was doing:

```
@echo off

set "fC=C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\AX copy"
set "latestC="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%fC%" /b /od /a-d /tw 2^>nul') do set "latest=%%a" & set "latestC=%fC%\%%a"

set "fD=C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\Reflex copy"
set "latestD="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%fD%" /b /od /a-d /tw 2^>nul') do set "latestD=%fD%\%%a"

if not defined latestC ( echo NO File in C & exit /b )
if not defined latestD ( echo NO File in D & exit /b )

for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (
    'diff "%latestC%" "%latestD%" ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
) do (
    >> "C:\Users\test\Important Structure\Development\Error\%latest%" echo(%%b
)
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.  There was a small addition to hide the error message when the folders have no files.

Comment: Hi Mate, I just needed to tweak the code slightly. If the two files have no difference I want the script to write out a .txt file titled "successful" and content "successful" please can you help with this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your diff command and don't know what output it gives.

Comment: Hi I was using the code which you wrote me above. I have managed to add the if exists command which seems to be doing the job.(if no diff file is generated it creates a new file which says successful)

Comment: if EXIST "\\3663vfas01\Biztalk$\Live\Files\Crystal\AuditArchive\Tmp Error\%latest%" (
echo Exist
) else echo PPM Successful >> "\\3663vfas01\Biztalk$\Live\Files\Crystal\AuditArchive\Succesful\Successful%latest%"
Pause

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need to do the equivalent of a `cd` command to a network path then you can use `pushd` for this, which temporally assigned a mapped drive e.g.

```
pushd "\\3663vfas01\Biztalk$\Live"
```

Comment: This does work but not for the ":getLatestFileInFolder" part as the file path there is in quotation marks and is being set further on in the code.